# Unity-UGUI) How to (UI A) move to (UI B)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to move ObjectImage A to ObjectImage B.

ObjectImage A and ObjectImage B are on the same canvas.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssTSb.png)
Object A = Ban33Stone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiClt.png)
Object B = Button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGDWk.png)
Grid = Object B.parent.parent

I dont know, but i tried..

```
    RectTransform rt = ObjectB.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    var screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(rt.position);
    var movePos = Vector2.zero;
    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(GameMainCanvas.transform as RectTransform
                                                        , screenPos
                                                        , Camera.main
                                                        , out movePos);
    ObjectA.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = GameMainCanvas.transform.TransformPoint(movePos);
```

Failed..

Comment: I don't quite understand your question ... if they are in the same canvas what speaks against `ObjectA.transform.position = ObjectB.transform.position;` ..?